# how to adjust other rows data based on a to be deleted row

Tags: sql, database, plsql, relational-database, plsqldeveloper

I have below addresses data in an oracle table for a person [ The mapping to particular person and other couple of fields are not shown].

```
**StartDate                 Address             EndDate** <br/>
```

1.  10-JAN-2015 10:52:23        1 Grimshaw          12-JAN-2015 11:30:15 
2.  12-JAN-2015 11:30:15        2 Ashwood           15-JAN-2015 03:17:05 
**3.    15-JAN-2015 03:17:05        5 Green Drive       13-FEB-2015 06:03:55** 
4.  13-FEB-2015 06:03:55        6 Lightfoot Close   18-FEB-2015 17:37:01 
5.  18-FEB-2015 17:37:01        7 Lightfoot Ln      15-MAR-2015 01:19:31

All of these addresses have proper date sequence. That means, a particular person is always having a valid address between 10-JAN-2015 and 15-MAR-2015 here].
The requirement is to, say delete one of the addresses and adjust the date accordingly so that there is no gap left. We are having a script which deletes the particular rows but unable to update the dates in other rows accordingly.
For example, if I delete the 3rd row in the above set then the end results should look like

```
**StartDate                 Address             EndDate** <br/>
```

1.  10-JAN-2015 10:52:23        1 Grimshaw          12-JAN-2015 11:30:15 
2.  12-JAN-2015 11:30:15        2 Ashwood           ***13-FEB-2015 06:03:55*** 
3.  13-FEB-2015 06:03:55        6 Lightfoot Close   18-FEB-2015 17:37:01 
4.  18-FEB-2015 17:37:01        7 Lightfoot Ln      15-MAR-2015 01:19:31

The EndDate of 2nd row is updated with the EndDate of deleted row [ i.e. 3rd row ].

**Note:**
The record numbers 1-5 here are just for illustrations purpose and table is not having any such columns.

Comment: r u using sql server or oracle?

Comment: Oracle... and mostly looking some innovative way of SQL or pl/sql otherwise...

Comment: is it always update the row having endate with start date of deleted row..in ur example start date of deleted row is 15 and u r updating the row having end date with 15..and u r updating the end date with end date of deleted row..is this same always?

Comment: did u tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this trigger by assuming the below condition

1. In table there will be a `person_id` column to represent each person
2. When a row is getting deleted the update will take place for the row having `End date` with `start date` of the deleted row
3. When deleting a row always the `EndDate` column value of the deleted row will  be used to update the `EndDate` column of the above row

   ```
   create or replace trigger product_update

   BEFORE DELETE on your_table_name
   for each row
   ```

   begin

   ```
   UPDATE your_table_name
      SET EndDate = :new.EndDate,
    WHERE EndDate = :new.StartDate
    AND PERSON_ID = :new.PERSON_ID;
   ```

   end;​

Answer (score 0):

I've coined the term Row Spanning Dependency for just the design pattern you show. That is where one column is dependent on another column but in a different row. The problem is that maintaining data integrity is a nightmare -- as you can see.

What I would recommend is to drop the EndDate column entirely. If that is something you have no power to do, then you can simply ignore it. The EndDate field serves no purpose whatsoever, except to make your life miserable.

Using only the StartDate field, the address starts at that time and continues until the next higher StartDate value. Thus, if you delete the designated row, the address that started on 12 Jan now just continues on until 13 Feb. You can later insert a new row with a StartDate of, say, 20 Jan and it fits nicely into the sequence: 12 Jan -> 20 Jan -> 13 Feb...

The important thing to realize is that each row is independent of other rows. You can Insert, Delete and Update to your heart's content and, as long as the date value remains unique, the sequence is never broken. The uniqueness is simply enforced by the StartDate being part of the PK.

Automatically, with no extra effort on your part, an unbroken sequence of dates is maintained, with no gaps and no everlaps possible. That point cannot be over-emphasized: there is no way possible to "break" the sequence. Even if two dates differ by only milliseconds (which probably means one of the date values is wrong), the sequence remains intact. If one of the dates is wrong, Update it to the correct value without worry about breaking the integrity of the sequence.

The query to see which address was active on a particular date is actually quite simple:

```
select  a.StartDate, a.Address
from    Addresses a
where   StartDate =(
        select  Max( StartDate )
        from    Addresses
        where   PersonID = a.PersonID
            and StartDate <= :AsOfDate );
```

You can reproduce the StartDate/EndDate form if you must:

```
select  a.StartDate, a.Address, a1.StartDate as EndDate
from    Addresses a
left join Addesses a1
    on  a1.PersonID = a.PersonID
    and a1.StartDate =(
        select  Min( StartDate )
        from    Addresses
        where   PersonID = a.PersonID
            and StartDate > a.StartDate );
```

The last date -- the one representing the "current" address -- will show an EndDate value of `NULL` which provides the added benefit of flagging the current row.

In fact, you can create a view based on the second query and give your users exactly what they are used to seeing. Another handy view would be based on the first query, but with `sysdate` instead of the parameter. That would show only the current addresses. Either way, now you don't have to hassle with keeping the StartDate value of one row and the EndDate value of a different row continually synchronized.